# Convert content:// URI to actual path for Android using React-Native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-camera

I am trying to upload images from `cameraRoll`. But the `cameraRoll` component returns a content:// URI, rather than an actual file path.

For uploading the image I need a file path, is there any way to convert a content:// URI to a file URI?

Example content URI:

```
content://com.miui.gallery.open/raw/%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FAndroid%2Fdata%2Fcom.miui.gallery%2Fcache%2FSecurityShare%2L78963157412.jpg
```

Comment: why do you need a path? cannot you use an `InputStream` for example?

Comment: I am developing a React-Native application and using Java methods is a bit cumbersome, so I am looking for a react native solution. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I took the function submitted by **@Madhukar Hebbar** and made it into a React Native Node Module.

You can find it here: [react-native-get-real-path](https://github.com/Wraptime/react-native-get-real-path)

Thus to achieve what you want, you can use the above module in conjunction with [react-native-fs](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs)

You can then do something like this when you want to upload the selected image from Camera Roll:

```
RNGRP.getRealPathFromURI(this.state.selectedImageUri).then(path =>
  RNFS.readFile(path, 'base64').then(imageBase64 =>
    this.props.actions.sendImageAsBase64(imageBase64)
  )
)
```

Comment: You are a saviour man! Just one concern - as it works only for android - need to put the require package line inside the platform checking logic. However comparing with the utility it is providing - I can ignore this. :-)

Comment: I have used your library but it didn't work. I get an error that `undefined is not a function(reactNativeGetRealPath2.default.getRealPathFromUri(path))` and the path that I give is `content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F890/ORIGINAL/NONE/225703422`

Comment: is there any library which gives support for both ios and android

Answer (score 9):

You can use `react-native-fs`'s `copyFile` method to convert content uri to file uri.

```
if (url.startsWith('content://')) {
    const urlComponents = url.split('/')
    const fileNameAndExtension = urlComponents[urlComponents.length - 1]
    const destPath = `${RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath}/${fileNameAndExtension}`
    await RNFS.copyFile(url, destPath)
}
```

Then you can use `'file://' + destPath` as expected

Comment: Please note: 
1. There are couple of variable name mistakes in the code.
2. If your filename is having '%' symbol in it, then it will not be uploaded. So, replace such characters.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the  `content:// URI` to below method to get the file path as string and then use the file object to do any operation.

```
File file = new File(getURIPath(uriValue));

/**
 * URI Value
 * @return File Path.
 */
String getURIPath(Uri uriValue) 
    {
        String[] mediaStoreProjection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriValue, mediaStoreProjection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null){ 
        int colIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String colIndexString=cursor.getString(colIndex);
        cursor.close();
        return colIndexString;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: How can I alter this function to work with all file types like documents and video files?