# react-native-fs stat Content URI with [Error: Unsupported Uri]

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-fs

I'm using `react-native-document-picker` to pick up a folder and using `react-native-fs` to save a file to that folder. Since `react-native-document-picker` returns a content uri not absolute path. I use `stat` to get the real path.

```js
try {
    const url = await DocumentPicker.pickDirectory()
    const stat = await RNFS.stat(`${url.uri}`)
    RNFS.writeFile(`${stat.path}/output.txt`, content, 'ascii')
} catch (e) {
    console.log('save failed', e)
}
```

I got error on Android (buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2", targetSdkVersion = 30 ):

```
save failed [Error: Unsupported Uri content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADocuments]
```

I've alread granted the external read/write permissions and set `ndroid:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in AndroidManifest.xml

Then how to convert the Content:// uri to real path and save file in it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/36259339/10718641

Comment: I tried `react-native-get-real-path`, it returns null on this content uri (directory)

Comment: Did you try any of the more recent solutions in that thread